# Quick question about Cantor's diagonal argument

Tags: real-analysis

Regarding the number we create from the diagonal of the hypothesized listing of all real numbers, could we just add 1 to each diagonal digit to create it, instead of the usual more complicated method?

What I mean is, suppose the diagonal of the list forms the number

a.bcdefg.... , where a, b, c... are digits.

Could we form the new number not on the hypothesized listing of all the reals by adding 1 to each of the digits a, b, c, d, e, ...?
I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work, which leaves me wondering why don't we use such a simpler method?

Comment: What would happen in your method with first entry $0.11000\ldots$ and second entry $0.2000\ldots$?  Wouldn't they both go to $0.21000\ldots$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  Yes, and so the created number differs from the first entry since its second digit is 2, and the second digit of the first entry is 1.  Similarly, it differs from the second entry, since they have different 3rd digits.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I hadn't thought of this detail, but I still can't see why it matters.  In the hypothesized listing, isn't every different real number represented only once?  So we can't have two equal numbers in the list, right?  That is, we either have 0.12349999..... or 0.12350000...., but not both.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ah, I see, yes, but I suspect that what you're suggesting is more of an additional precaution rather than a clear failure of the method, because for this to become a problem, the created new number would have to *terminate* with repeating 0's or 9's, but, this seems impossible to me.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks.  I'd accept this as an answer.  I in fact forgot that the list didn't have to be randomised in any way.  It could be designed to counter this sort of simplified approach.

Comment: I will gather together my previous comments and shape them into an answer, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deal with the fact that the decimal representation is not unique: $0.123499999\ldots$ and $0.12350000\ldots$ are the same number. So you have to mess up more with the digits, for instance by using the permutation $(0,5)(1,6)(2,7)(3,8)(4,9)$ - this is safe since no digit is mapped into an adjacent digit.

In the hypothetical listing every real number is represented only once, but maybe by perturbing the diagonal in a soft way you may get an *equivalent* representation for a number already listed, that is the issue. Let us consider the hypothetical listing

$$ \begin{array}{rcl}1&:& 0.\color{red}{1}06752\ldots \\ 2&:& 0.1\color{red}{9}9999\ldots \\ 3&:& 0.20\color{red}{9}652\ldots \\ 4&:& 0.346\color{red}{9}33\ldots\end{array} $$
By taking the diagonal and adding $1$ to each digit you get $0.2000\ldots$, which is already in the list, just in a equivalent form.

Answer (score 1):

Adding one would be fine,  i believe.  but I don't really believe this is any simpler:  it's merely a particular way of changing the diagonal entry.  Any way will do:  you can change the diagonal entry to any different digit;  and you will produce a number not in the list...

Comment: This is what I thought, except that every example of the proof I've seen uses some less straightforward function to create the new number.  Adding one seems as simple as it gets.  Also, in the comments, Jack seems to disagree.  Can you please help address his comment?

Comment: Well, one does have to agree beforehand that a unique representation for each real number is restricted to...  it's an important detail...  but then the argument goes through (I think)

Comment: You don't want your new number to end in all 9's, which might already be in the list in the form ending with all 0's. And by adding 1 at each stage, if your original list eventually had all 8's on the diagonal, you could end up with a new number ending with all 9's. It's easy to avoid by not using 9's in your new number even if it makes the rule trivially more complicated.

Comment: If you agree beforehand that each real number has only one valid representation, then you would need to be careful that the diagonalization argument doesn't create an invalid representation of some real number (which might happen to have its valid representation be in the list).